# Folium choropleth maps in layers lose scale - how to fix?

Tags: geojson, folium, choropleth

How can I get the scale/legend to display?

I can get Folium to produce choropleth maps individually; they always include the scale and legend.

I've also figured out how to get them grouped into FeatureGroups, so I can display different layers on one map (see code below).

But when I do so, the scale / legend disappears. This makes the maps much less intelligible! Is there a way to fix this?

```py
m = folium.Map(location=[40, -96],tiles = None)

for group in groups:
  layer = folium.FeatureGroup(name = group, overlay = False).add_to(m)
  
  cp = folium.Choropleth(
          geo_data = counties,
          data = map_df, 
          columns = ['FIPS','ScaleTotPop'],
          key_on = 'feature.properties.FIPS',
          bins = 9,
          fill_color='OrRd',
          fill_opacity=0.8,
          line_opacity=0.2,
          nan_fill_color = 'grey',
          legend_name='Percent of county population'
          ).geojson.add_to(layer) # <- WHY geojson here?

folium.TileLayer('OpenStreetMap',overlay=True,control = False).add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. You need to ask one question in wach post. Kindly take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Thanks and my apologies for not following good practice. I've edited this post to remove the Q2 and Q3. I will create separate posts for them.